# Giant Power Pro no longer reading power on right crank after washing bike

Tags: power, giant

2020 Giant TCR Advanced Pro. I washed the bike and per the title, the right side power reading has gone to zero. The right side still lights up and charges, and I was able to use RideLink to update firmware, but I cannot calibrate (fails with error 000ee22 in a message box). It still gives power readings, but they're about 4-5x too high, and left-sided in the power balance.

Given it is just a lump glued to my crank, I can't really think of what to try. It was supposed to be ipx7 waterproof! Anyone have any ideas?

[unfortunately I am the second owner and Giant Australia have previously told me I have no warranty and should've bought new and supported the brand]

Edit: The first ride was about 3 days after the wash, and it read 1000w on one side, after about a week it started giving some readings on the other side, but still inflated altogether; and finally on day 10 I gave it 5 minutes with a hairdryer on low and tried a ride and it read totally back to normal! It's a sealed unit glued on to the crank, so there's nothing I could do apart from just give it time, and the hairdryer. If this happens to you, hold out hope for at least 10 days to see if it finally dries out unharmed.

Comment: The inflated power readings are interesting. I have a double-sided aftermarket PM and on two occasions when the (replaceable) battery on one side expired, the power reading inflated for a few minutes (1200-1900W). The system is supposed to convert from a dual to a single-sided system when this happens, but it hasn't been seamless. I believe that it was caused by one side ceasing to send power at very low battery but still connected wirelessly to the other side. Your inflated power readings could be related to a similar failure to disengage the dead side and transition to single-sided operation

Comment: Excellent work with the results, thank you for coming back to share.  I'd probably avoid thinking of it as "sealed" because clearly its not waterproof.  I couldn't say whether attempting to seal it better with silicon, or conformal spray coating, or any other product would help or hinder.   Maybe avoid riding it in the rain, and be ultra-careful when washing it in the future.  Perhaps bagging the crank completely in plastic and tape would help while washing.

Comment: Good point to assume it isn't sealed anymore. I'm loathe to mess with it with silicon or anything, so I think I'll just stick with keeping it dry - bagging for washes and not riding in the rain (not that I ride in the rain anyway!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you got water in it somehow.

As a fix, remove the battery if possible, and open every port/access panel in the area then position bike in warm dry sunlight.

Or put it in a small sealed room with a dehumidifier running overnight.  Bathrooms are good, if you put plugs in all the drains.

I've heard of people putting dunked phones into a sealed container of dry white rice to extract moisture, but you'd have to pull the crank.

Good luck!    Your only other option might be to ask the original owner to help with warranty, if you have contact details.

Comment: I think one thing to add would be turn the thing off and leave it off while it dries. Trying to operate it could short circuit and damage something on the circuit board.

Comment: You can buy bulk silica gel and refresh it in the oven. That's better than rice. You can also get an oven to 30-50 Celsius with a bit of care, which dries electronics nicely.